# Scraping with JQuery or Python?

Tags: jquery, python, screen-scraping

So lets say I'm scraping multiple pages (lets say a 1000) on a website. I want to know which language is best to use to scrape those pages with - javascript or python.

Further, I've heard about javascript scrapers being faster (due to multiple get requests), but am unsure how to implement this - can anyone enlighten me?

Thanks!

Comment: Not JS, but anything serverside, like Python, PHP, Rails etc. will do. PHP is probably the language that is mostly use for that kind of thing.

Comment: @adeneo: JS is server-side too.

Comment: @amnotiam - Yes, if using Node.js etc. but anyone who knows how to make their own http server in Node or set up Express properly, probably doesn't need the answer to this question though?

Comment: @adeneo: I don't think so. The question is asking which is the best language. *(I assume that implies the best environment, including NodeJS.)* There's no indication that OP knows anything about JS or Python, or at least how they may compare.

Comment: @amnotiam - Ok, lets just agree that JS on the clientside is useless for doing any scraping, and on the serverside if scraping many pages at the same time, node.js is probably fastest due to being eventbased and not thread based. For simplisity PHP is probably the language with most tutorials on how to make a simple cURL scraper, the other languages, and there are many, are probably somewhere inbetween, but most will perform better than a simple PHP cURL scraper on a server.

Comment: @adeneo: python is not specifically thread based. It can be as a solution. It can also be event based, or process based. Choose a framework.

Comment: If you really want to use javascript and not use node.js, you could write a scraper using PhantomJS: http://www.phantomjs.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is just my opinion but I would rank them like this

- javascript might be the best choice but only if you have a node
  environment already set up. The advantage of javascript scrapers is
  they can interpret the js in the pages you're scraping.
- next is a three way tie between perl python and ruby. They all have a mechanize library and do xpath and regex in a sensible way.
- Down at the bottom is php. It's lack of a cookie handling library like mechanize (curl isn't great) and it's clumsy dom and regex functions make it a poor choice for scraping.

Comment: If you do go for Python, try `beautifulsoup` instead of using regexes.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading your question right, you're not trying to build a web app (client- or server-side), but rather a standalone app that simply requests and downloads pages from the Web.

You *can* write a standalone app in JavaScript, but it's not common. The primary use of JavaScript is for code that's going to run in a user's Web browser. For standalone apps, Python is the better choice. And it has very good support (in the form of the `urllib2` and related libraries) for tasks like Web scraping.

Of course, if your scraping task is relatively simple, you might be better off just using `wget`.

Comment: At this point there is a much larger choice of web-scraping tools for JS, and they are (imho) superior to mechanize and analogous tools for python. `urllib2` hasn't been sufficient for a long time as it does not handle state or javascript.